# How to execute a script saved in the local system from a remote server?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, remote

I want to execute a script saved on the local system from a remote Unix server to help me automate a deployment process. The script contains some commands to rename an existing file on the remote Unix server and then transfer a new file from the local system to the Unix server.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something along the lines of `cat localscriptfile.sh | ssh remotehost 'cat - | sh'`, perhaps? I haven't tested that, but maybe it can get you started. It avoids having to copy the actual file or making the server aware of your local file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool of your choice is `ssh`. 
Simply call `ssh user@remoteHost remoteScript` to trigger the invocation on the local system  from the remote unix server. See `man ssh` for further details.

If the script is not already on the destination machine, you have two ways to achieve it.

#### via scp

```
function remoteCallSCP() { # <remoteAccount> <script> <interpreter> [arguments}       
   local remoteAccount=${1}
   local script=${2}
   shift scriptRunner=${3} 
   shift 3 # script arguments are following
   local tmpFile=$(mktemp) # not perfect, but 99% good
   scp ${script} ${remoteAccount}:${tmpFile} # executable bit is lost
   ssh ${remoteAccount} ${scriptRunner} ${tmpFile}
```

}

#### via ssh and *stdin*

```
 function remoteCallStdIn() { # <remoteAccount> <script>
     local remoteAccount=${1}
     local script=${2}
     ssh -T ${remoteAccount}  <${script}
}
```

The `-T` option disable pseudo-tty allocation. Which may help to fix some weird issues.

The following features are missing here:

- The script has to be a shell script compatible to the default shell of the remote account.
- Command line arguments are not working.

As a maintainable workaround you may think about custom generated scripts as input, that are containing interpreter and arguments.